# How can I prepopulate the remainder of forms based on user input from a first form?

Tags: javascript, django, html, django-forms

So what I'd like tot do is have a list of forms that show up based on what the user picked in a page before. Now after entering the information in the first form, I would like to give the option of repeating that information for the additional forms . Ex.:

activity 1
Name 1
Name 2
Email

activity 2
Name 1 
Name 2 
Email

You can see how it can become redundant and tedious if you sign up for many activities. How would I do this in django if possible or javascript if i need to or even html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with just HTML5 and JavaScript (I have no idea what Django is, but this'll be easier if Django is a server-side language that can access form data).

I would make the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element in the first webpage lead to the second webpage so that the second webpage would have the GET parameters of that form data, and then in the JavaScript of the second webpage, use those GET parameters to put in data into the form. Here's an example:

tester1.html:

```
[...]
<form action = "tester2.html">
  <input name = "realname" />
  <input name = "screenname" />
  <input type = "submit" />
</form>
[...]
```

tester2.html:

```
[...]
<script>
var form;
window.onload = function() {
    var url = document.location.href;
    var keys = url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1, url.length).split("&");
    form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) form[keys[i].substring(0, keys[i].indexOf("="))].value = decodeURIComponent(keys[i].substring(keys[i].indexOf("=")+1, keys[i].length));
};
</script>
[...]

<form>
  <input name = "realname" />
  <input name = "screenname" />
  <input type = "password" name = "password" />
  <input type = "submit" />
</form>
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you, In case anyone was wondering how to do this with django, just send the values as a POST and then request them with request.POST.get(), after doing that, assign the variables and insert them into the next form.